# How to get Many to Many relation data?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a NodeJS app that uses PostgresQL and I'm trying to retrieve some relational data:

I have a `Movie` table which has a relation with my `User` table:

```
// prisma.schema

model Movie {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  original_title   String           @unique
  tmdb_id          Int              @unique
  poster_path      String?         
  backdrop_path    String?         
  release_date     String?
  runtime          Int?
  tagline          String?         
  overview         String?         
  users            User[]
  notification     Notification[]
  movieRating      MovieRating[]
}  
  
model User {  
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  email            String           @unique
  user_name        String           @unique
  password         String
  movies           Movie[]
  notifications    Notification[]
  followedBy       User[]           @relation("UserFollows", references: [id])
  following        User[]           @relation("UserFollows", references: [id])
  notification     Notification[]   @relation("FollowedUser")
  movieRating      MovieRating[]
  resetToken       String?          @unique
  activationToken  String?          @unique
}
```

In my back-end I want to select all users that have a relation to a movie: (17 is the id of a movie)

`const users = await pool.query('SELECT id, user FROM "Movie" WHERE id = $1', [17]);`

I would expect an array of id's from the table user from table movie row 17. But the actual result is:

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: null,
  rows: [ { id: 17, user: 'db_user' } ],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 189397,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'user',
      tableID: 0,
      columnID: 0,
      dataTypeID: 19,
      dataTypeSize: 64,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    }
  ],
  _parsers: [ [Function: parseInteger], [Function: noParse] ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

Something is happening but definitely not what I expected. `db_user` is the user name of my database...

Comment: Your table has "users" column while in the query you are using "user" and not "users".

Comment: > error: column "users" does not exist if I just use `users`. I think that makes sense since users isn't a column, but the relation between the 2 tables.

Comment: Result is an object which return not only query resukt but also additional informations (like described in documentation). And you are interested in result.rows node

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't checked that it's a many to many relationship. If the tables were generated by your ORM , then there should be a third table which maps the id of movie table and I'd of the user table. You can run query on that table and get the desired result.

Comment: @Kadet fair enough, but the row information is incorrect as well. It returns `db_user` and not the user `id` that has a relation to the movie `id` 17.

Comment: @Khopadi ah yea, there's a `MovieToUser` table.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma  `user` is a reserved word for Postgresql to return current user. If you want user name or list of user names you must ask different query but I'm not prisma specialist